# Reopen votes can be cast on deleted questions

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, vote-to-reopen

Fiddling around on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357120/my-account-has-suddenly-vanished-what-has-happened) deleted question, I accidentally hit the "Reopen" button. Curious, I followed through, and it actually appeared to cast my vote, without screaming at me:

[image]

Why doesn't it show the error:

[image]

That is shown when a deleted question is voted to be *closed*?  Can we make it show the error when you hit "reopen", since deleted questions aren't supposed to be voted on?

Comment: @Rob Can't believe I missed that.  I'm sure I searched thoroughly... Supported using the ubiquitous upvote.

Comment: Tip: Searching for [the tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deleted-questions+vote-to-reopen) shows that there's a prior duplicate.